# Shared Docker devicemapper lvm thinpool in a multiboot setup

Tags: docker

I'm developing using Docker on a multiboot setup under both Fedora and Ubuntu on my laptop. I need this to rule out issues with selinux and/or apparmor so my build will work for both red hat(and friends) and debian(and friends).

I'm using devicemapper in thin pool lvm configuration as storage backend. This was configured using docker-storage-setup tool under Fedora.

I would like to share my docker images and containers to both Fedora (/ is formatted as ext4fs on lvm) and Ubuntu environments (/ is formatted as btrfs also on lvm) to save space.

However after one Docker system has started and taken over the docker thinpool, the other Docker system could not use the same docker thinpool.

This is the error:

```
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Unable to take ownership of thin-pool ("my docker thin pool") that already has used data blocks
```

Based on that it seems to have this limitation by design. In that case would anyone elaborate on my particular use case and is there another way to share my docker devicemapper thin pool with several linux systems so I can save space and not have duplicate images/containers?

Answer (score 0):

In a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1321640#c5) Eric Paris says:

> IF you are using device mapper (instead of loopback) /var/lib/docker contains metadata informing docker about the contents of the device mapper storage area. If you delete /var/lib/docker that metadata is lost. Docker is then able to detect that the thin pool has data but docker is unable to make use of that information. The only solution is to delete the thin pool and recreate it so that both the thin pool and the metadata in /var/lib/docker will be empty.

So syncing parts of `/var/lib/docker` may be a solution.

Comment: I'm using devicemapper and my thin pool has both data and metadata. The problem is only one OS can use and take over the volume but my end case is I want both data and metadata shared in a multiboot OS setup.

Comment: Following instructions from [docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-direct-lvm-mode-for-production) I created thinpool with `lvconvert -y --zero n -c 512K --thinpool docker/thinpool --poolmetadata docker/thinpoolmeta`. Using it worked fine. Then I deleted `/var/lib/docker` as I thought it would not be needed. Then same error as mentioned in the question occured.